# Vuetify remove brackets when there is no data in JSON v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a list of data and for some of the objects in the data the tag key is empty. When plotting the data in the table they data which has tag key is plotted correctly but for the object which doesn't have the tag key it is being displayed as []. How do I remove that ?

```
            <template v-slot:[`item.tags`]="item">
            {{item.tags}}
            </template>
```

Data Sample for a data with tag

```
 {"_id": {"$oid": "60c057823e2a3a534cb1b412"}, 
  "tags": "MMM", 
  "DateModified": "2021-06-09 13:54:57"}
```

Data Sample for a data without tag

```
  {"_id": {"$oid": "60c057823e2a3a534cb1b412"}, 
  "tags": [], 
  "DateModified": "2021-06-09 13:54:57"}
```

[image: Table sample]

Comment: can you share the data sample, what type of data is in tag key ?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar sample data has been added

Comment: So tags can contains  multiple tags ?

Comment: @CharlesLavalard it can contain only one single tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you different type of data for each of case when you have data and when you don't have data.

Better go with this

```
<template v-slot:[`item.tags`]="item">
            {{item.tags.length === 0 ? '' : item.tags}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `tags` field is an array, you do not want to directly call `{{tags}}` in your template. You should probably have something like

```html
<span v-for="(tag, i) in tags" :key="i">{{tag}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your default tags

If i can contain at most 1 tags it should be an empty String instead of an empty Array

your data Sample for a data without tag

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "60c057823e2a3a534cb1b412"}, 
    "tags": '', 
    "DateModified": "2021-06-09 13:54:57"
  }
```